# score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true' scikitlearn, crossvalidation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to make a simple crossvalidation process by scikitlearn, crossvalidate, and I get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-0471fb78d8f0> in <module>
      5 
      6 model = NMF(n_components=185, init='random', random_state=0)
----> 7 scores = cross_validate(model, df4_array, cv=5, scoring=('neg_mean_squared_error'))
      8 W = model.fit_transform(df4_array)
      9 H = model.components_

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    234             return_times=True, return_estimator=return_estimator,
    235             error_score=error_score)
--> 236         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    237 
    238     zipped_scores = list(zip(*scores))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    919             # remaining jobs.
    920             self._iterating = False
--> 921             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    922                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    923 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    542     else:
    543         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
--> 544         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    545         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    546         if return_train_score:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    587         scorer = _MultimetricScorer(**scorer)
    588     if y_test is None:
--> 589         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    590     else:
    591         scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
     85             if isinstance(scorer, _BaseScorer):
     86                 score = scorer._score(cached_call, estimator,
---> 87                                       *args, **kwargs)
     88             else:
     89                 score = scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)

TypeError: _score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'
```

I do not know why, because I am trying to do a Recommender System for tue University using Non negative matrix factorization, which is an unsupervised method ... shouldn`t the code work without y?

Code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import  mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error,  r2_score

model = NMF(n_components=185, init='random', random_state=0)
scores = cross_validate(model, df4_array, cv=5, scoring=('neg_mean_squared_error'))
W = model.fit_transform(df4_array)
H = model.components_
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but, do you mean the full code?

Comment: No, I would assume that is the error is in the provided code.  I meant the full Error traceback.

Comment: To understand the crossvalidated error I think you would find this link useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354611/pattern-of-out-of-sample-reconstruction-error-in-nmf-cross-validation-why-is-it

Answer (score 2):

So I think the problem is with the scoring method.

Any form of MSE(mean_squared_error) is a function for regression type problems as the formula involves a dependent variable(y) component of regression.

I would suggest to look through this link for different unsupervised scoring methods.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter

Hope this helped.

May the force be with you.